# What designation is shown in the diagram?

Tags: arduino, pcb-design

I found the circuit of the module I am interested in, but I can't figure out what the numbers are before and after the resistors (marked with red ovals). Can you tell me what they mean in the diagram?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are pin numbers for resistor arrays, probably something similar to one of these chip resistor arrays:

[image: Resistor array]

*([Source](https://www.siricomindia.com/products/chip-resistor-array/))*

Note that these can be found in various configurations other than having all resistor terminations exposed as pins. They may also be called resistor networks.

Comment: For clarification, the designator "RN" in the schematic is a short for "Resistor Network".

Comment: @Justme Thanks, I've added that.

Comment: @JYelton That is, it's just an assembly of resistors of the same nominal value? At the same time, the numbers on them are the designation of the pins in the assembly?

Comment: @Settings yep. That's it.

Comment: @InBedded16 OK, thanks a lot)